# Modal in Angular $injector:unpr Unknown

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-bootstrap

I'm having this problem trying to use modals in angular

```
$modalProvider <- $modal <- User.Ctlr
```

Here's my app.js

```
'use-strict';

var App = angular.module('App', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

Here's my controller

'use strict';

```
App.controller('User.Ctlr', ['$scope', '$modal', '$http', function ($scope, $modal, $http) { 
}]);
```

Here's my HTML

```
<body ng-app="App">
    <div class="container" ng-controller="User.Ctlr">
     </div>
</body>
<script src="/scripts/lib/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/lib/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/lib/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/app/app.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/app/controllers/userCtrl.js"></script>
```

I'm not understanding what could be wrong, it used to work properly when I didn't have modals, so my controller was exactly the same but the variable $modal.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject `$modalInstance` instead of modal

```
app.controller('User.Ctlr', function ($scope, $modalInstance, $http)
{
   //Use modalInstance
});
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/zHzQU09RI6bKcDtC8bzy?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
<script src="/scripts/lib/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

For

```
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.9.0.js"></script>
```

And now it's working properly! 
Thanks